# Expectation Initializers with mockserver java not load

Tags: java, maven, mockserver

I use mockserver ([mock-server](https://mock-server.com/)) on my java project and now I want to start it with a persistent Expectation Initializers with the mvn command. I tested it with a json file and it work correctly, but when I use or rather start it with an Expectation Initializers (Java file) the configuration is not load on startup from the mock-server, because the file was not found.
The command used is:

`mvn -Dmockserver.initializationClass="mockserver.ExpectationInitializer" mockserver:run`

The structure of my example project is:
[image]

And my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>java-example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-client-java-no-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverPort>1080</serverPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The following error, which I get when I start the command:

```
        $ mvn -Dmockserver.initializationClass="mockserver.ExampleInitializationClass" mockserver:run
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ----------------------< org.example:java-example >----------------------
    [INFO] Building java-example 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                      
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] --- mockserver-maven-plugin:5.13.2:run (default-cli) @ java-example --- 
    [INFO] mockserver:run about to start MockServer on:  serverPort [1080]
    [ERROR] Exception loading class expectation initializer                
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mockserver.ExampleInitializationClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)     
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)          
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass (URLClassLoader.java:897)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.mockserver.maven.MockServerAbstractMojo.createInitializerClass (MockServerAbstractMojo.java:169)
        at org.mockserver.maven.MockServerRunAndWaitMojo.execute (MockServerRunAndWaitMojo.java:40)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    [INFO] loading class initialization file:

      mockserver.ExampleInitializationClass

    [WARNING] exception while loading JSON initialization class, ignoring class:

      mockserver.ExampleInitializationClass

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mockserver.ExampleInitializationClass
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.mockserver.server.initialize.ExpectationInitializerLoader.retrieveExpectationsFromInitializerClass (ExpectationInitializerLoader.java:82)
        at org.mockserver.server.initialize.ExpectationInitializerLoader.addExpectationsFromInitializer (ExpectationInitializerLoader.java:61)
        at org.mockserver.server.initialize.ExpectationInitializerLoader.<init> (ExpectationInitializerLoader.java:43)
        at org.mockserver.mock.HttpState.<init> (HttpState.java:126)
        at org.mockserver.lifecycle.LifeCycle.<init> (LifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.mockserver.netty.MockServer.<init> (MockServer.java:77)
        at org.mockserver.netty.MockServer.<init> (MockServer.java:48)
        at org.mockserver.maven.InstanceHolder.start (InstanceHolder.java:56)
        at org.mockserver.maven.MockServerRunAndWaitMojo.execute (MockServerRunAndWaitMojo.java:50)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    [INFO] 1080 started on port: 1080
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in the test package.
In my case, I'm using these dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
      <version>${mock-sever-netty-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockserver-client-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mock-sever-netty-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with this properties

```
  <properties>
    <mock-sever-netty-version>5.13.2</mock-sever-netty-version>
    <apche-http-version>4.4.1</apche-http-version>
  </properties>
```

Then I have a principal class that sets the initializer class

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("mockserver.initializationClass",
            ExpectationInitializerMock.class.getName());
        ClientAndServer mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
    }
}
```